# cant access woocommerce cart in contact form 7 hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using the the wpcf7 hook wpcf7_special_mail_tags() I want to get the cart contents and return the output, but WC()->cart object is null in this hook, I cant access any methods on WC()->cart as its a *call to an undefined method*. I cant work out how to get access to WC()->cart in this hook.

I can access WC()->cart fine in the WPCF7 hook wpcf7_add_form_tag()

The wpcf7_special_mail_tags() works fine and inserts other data into email, I just want cart data though.

Thanks for any help.

```
function my_special_mail_tag( $output, $name, $html ) {
    if ( 'mytag' == $name ) {
  
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    if(!WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
     // do something with output
    }
  }
 
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'my_special_mail_tag', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Using your function, if I pass `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents()` and if I go inside your `if(!WC()->cart->is_empty())` and define $output as something... it appears in the email. So what you have appears to work for me.

Comment: I add the following tag to the contact form mail html:  [mytag]

Comment: Do you mean to say you pass WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as a argument to my_special_mail_tag(), that's how you can access the cart ?

Comment: I was able to access the cart yes.

Comment: Fantastic, @HowardE I haven't ever passed an argument to a hook before like this, did you use a closure? If your able to paste your code so I can see how you passed this in, as I have never done so before.

Comment: I used your code.

Comment: So you didn't pass WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as a argument, you were just able to use my code to access the cart obj and its methods even though when I do it throws an error as null object with undefined methods. Odd, I'll test this again in the morning. I'm kinda glad you didn't pass it in as argument, as I wouldn't be able to unhook it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I'm ok with this.

```
function my_special_mail_tag( $output, $name, $html ) {
    if ( 'mytag' == $name ) {
  
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    if(!WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
     // do something with output
    }
  }
 
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'my_special_mail_tag', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Can you confirm you can access WC()->cart from this hook?

Comment: Yes can I tested already.